# PHP put variable consists of multiple values to be converted to array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to use a variable to be converted to array. My variable consists of the combination of multiple variables. I want to convert them, but could not able to find the good answer on the web.

```
<?php
$var1="ABC";
$var2="DEF";

$id = $var1.",".$var2;
$info = array($id, 'Ex2', 'Example');
print_r($info);
?>
```

Right now the result is

```
Array ( [0] => ABC,DEF [1] => Ex2 [2] => Example )
```

I want it to be something like

```
Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => DEF [2] => Ex2 [3] => Example )
```

Appreciate your help,thank you in advance.

**Edit: I know I can achieve this through array($var1, $var2, 'Ex2', 'Example'); but I am preparing the $id in a loop. The value of $id will be appended and I want them to be converted into an array based on my requirements.

Comment: just read the [manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: May i know why you just did `$id = $var1.",".$var2;` ?

Comment: @Shankar I am preparing the value in a loop. so I will append the $id variable so that I can convert it into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally hate this approach though.

```
<?php
$var1="ABC";
$var2="DEF";

$id = $var1.",".$var2;
$id=explode(',',$id);
$info = array('Ex2', 'Example');
$info = array_merge($id,$info);
print_r($info);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC
    [1] => DEF
    [2] => Ex2
    [3] => Example
)
```

Comment: Cheers, thank you, this is what I want, sometimes this trick is needed due to the requirements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = array($var1, $var2, 'Ex2', 'Example');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this :

```
<?php
$var1="ABC";
$var2="DEF";

$id = array($var1, $var2)
$temp = array('Ex2', 'Example');
$info = array_merge($id, $temp);
print_r($info);
?>
```